# filtering spam emails with Chinese subject

Tags: spam, spamassassin, spam-filter, sieve

A client have ton of Chinese spam. All look similar to this one:

```
Return-Path: <15308409199@189.cn>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.4.0 (2014-02-07) on
    hotel492.dedicatedpanel.com
X-Spam-Level: ***
X-Spam-Status: No, score=3.2 required=5.0 tests=BAYES_50,
    FREEMAIL_ENVFROM_END_DIGIT,FREEMAIL_FROM,FROM_LOCAL_DIGITS,FROM_LOCAL_HEX,
    RCVD_IN_RP_RNBL,RDNS_NONE,SPF_FAIL,SPF_HELO_FAIL,UNPARSEABLE_RELAY
    autolearn=no autolearn_force=no version=3.4.0
Delivered-To: info@MYDOMAIN.com
Received: from qq.com (unknown [117.63.78.83])
    by mail.MYSERVER.com (Postfix) with SMTP id E99E441FF0E23
    for <info@MYDOMAIN.com>; Mon, 12 Feb 2018 01:28:59 +0100 (CET)
Received: from qq.com (unknown (210.16.9.24])
     by qq.com with SMTP id a96dedeb-c1f9-4f5b-b79c-0ff8b77d40e4;
     for <15308409199@189.cn>;Mon, 12 Feb 2018 08:28:46 +08:00
Message-ID: <98f7bcd1aac2f30dc4fea8d01cd47e69@189.cn>
From: "=?utf-8?B?55m96Im+6KeC?=" <15308409199@189.cn>
To: <info@MYDOMAIN.com>
Subject: =?utf-8?B?5ZOI5Za977yB546w6YKA5oKo6aKGMzjlnIYg6K+35Zyo44CQMzM0OTQ454K5Y29t?=
    =?utf-8?B?44CR5rOo5YaMVklQIOivpuaDheS8gem5heS4k+WRmOOAkDI3MjAwMDUz?=
    =?utf-8?B?MzfjgJHlkqjor6JWSVDlkajlkajpooblt6XotYQg5L+456aE5pyI5pyI?=
    =?utf-8?B?5ou/IOWkqeWkqemDveaciee6ouWMhembqCDlrp7lipvlubPlj7Ag5Ye65qy+?=
    =?utf-8?B?5a6J5YWo5L+d6Zqc?=
Date: Mon, 12 Feb 2018 08:28:46 +0800
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Disposition-Notification-To: 15308409199@189.cn
```

There is no body on the emails and subject is different each time. qq.com is not present in all emails either.

I tried to block using spamassassin, but it can not do much, so I decided to use sieve to move all emails with Chinese / Japanese / Korean charset in different folder.

Is this somehow possible?

*Uptate*

Tried variations of following, does not work.

```
if body :raw :contains "ubject: =?utf-8?B?" {
    fileinto "Junk";
}
```

Comment: The body doesn't contain the subject line, the header does. I'd filter on the from line myself.

Comment: can i do headers :raw :contains ? does not work, but you get the idea

Comment: Perhaps not, but you tagged this question with spamassassin and spamassassin has no problem matching header lines.

Comment: assassin was unable to match this as spam, so I tried to find solution using Spamassassin or Dovecot. The way I fixed the problem is blocking list (spamcop) from postfix.

Answer (score 1):

You should block all IPs found in https://intodns.com/qq.com

Here is the list of IPs I have blocked, but you should check every now and then because IPs keep getting changed/added:

```
101.226.68.138
14.17.19.139
101.227.169.106 
182.140.167.157
182.140.177.149 
123.151.178.115
125.39.247.247
184.105.206.124
203.205.144.156
87.243.6.138  
87.243.6.136 

MX
184.105.206.32 
184.105.206.30 
184.105.206.31 
184.105.206.86 
184.105.206.85 
184.105.206.82 
103.7.30.40
203.205.176.244
203.205.176.240
```

They are still coming but at least they go straight to queue and eventually to garbage.